# Question regarding faith

Tags: imaan

Asaalam alaikum brothers and sisters.

I have been wondering recently, a bit too much I think; pondering on some questions.

A common question I see from people of other faiths and atheists that “why does Allah have people born into poverty” or other questions like “why does Allah not prevent accidents or disasters from happening and have “innocent” people die?”. With these questions, I don’t have sufficient knowledge to explain why apart from telling them that he’s testing our faith. But is there a proper explanation, or is it better to not question these things?

Also, there are some other things I question such as where people say when we sleep; Allah takes our soul and during that time we are dead. But how come we are breathing and there is brain activity even when we are asleep if we are dead?

Also, what is Islam’s view on Evolution? Islam says Adam and Eve are the first humans, but then historians say we have ancestors who are Neanderthals and other non-modern humans. Does that mean Adam and Eve were Neanderthals or were they modern-humans? What do we believe on Evolution?

Is it wrong that I’m questioning these things? Is it permissible in Islam? Recently I’ve had these thoughts and I’m worried it will weaken my faith in Islam. Is this a common problem amongst Muslims?

Comment: There's 9 questions marks in this question.  Can we narrow it down to just [one question per question](https://islam.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2965/why-we-should-avoid-asking-multi-question-questions)?

Comment: Consider splitting your questions by asking them as distinct questions/posts so that each of them can be fully addressed.

Comment: Wonderful! Somebody who is curious. Try to find the answers for yourself and don't just believe what others tell you. Always question everything. :-)

Comment: Please split your questions; but for Islam's view about Evolution theory have a look at http://www.islamquest.net/en/archive/question/fa4014

Answer (score -3):

> Why does Allah have people born into poverty?

People are born all over the world, so people are also born in poverty. I guess your question is more like: "Why does Allah allow the unbalanced distribution of prosperity we can see around the world?" As I see it most people use outer pleasures to hide their inner discomfort. But the human mind quite quickly adjusts to what it has, so it always needs more and more to push aside the discomfort. This ignorant behaviour is not really working as more and more people (for instance in the USA) get psychological disorders, depressions, drug addictions and so on. As to why Allah allows this? I would say that this is all part of Allah's great plan for humanity. Meaning it is part of evolution. Why would we think about evolution as something that has been and ended? Doesn't it make more sense that it is still going on? More and more people are suffering from their minds/thoughts and emotions and the next step for humanity is to overcome this.

> Why does Allah not prevent accidents or disasters from happening and have innocent people die?

If Allah is the greatest, who is in everything and everywhere always, then he is also in every human being acting through all of them. In the end there are no accidents or disasters, just life happening. It is only our judgemental mind that categorizes the outer for us, that sees this as good and that as bad.

> Or is it better to not question these things?

Always question everything. Even what I write here.

> Also, there are some other things I question such as where people say
>   when we sleep; Allah takes our soul and during that time we are dead.
>   But how come we are breathing and there is brain activity even when we
>   are asleep if we are dead?

There is no such thing as an individual soul. It is just a concept of a higher self that is created by the mind that is afraid of death. So the mind invents a higher self that is going to live on, after the body is no more. There is only life and life alone. All life is Allah the great and only one. When we fall asleep we become unconscious, but as you said the brain activity goes on. When you sleep the mind and your thoughts still cycle around the things that worry you. But other things get mixed in. So our dreams are only the modified versions of our daily though processes. That is why dreams can help you to identify what is on your mind.

> Also, what is Islam’s view on Evolution? Islam says Adam and Eve are
>   the first humans, but then historians say we have ancestors who are
>   Neanderthals and other non-modern humans. Does that mean Adam and Eve
>   were Neanderthals or were they modern-humans? What do we believe on
>   Evolution?

The story of Adam and Eve is only a metaphor. Most stories in the holy books (Bible, Quran, Tao-te-king, and so on) are metaphors that are not meant to be taken literally. Literally most of them don't even make sense. If you ask me, life itself is evolution. It is constantly changing. Allah does not seem to like equal things. No two people are exactly the same. Nor are two leaves on a tree ever exactly the same. Allah seems to like change. So all life is evolution and change.

> Is it wrong that I’m questioning these things? Is it permissible in
>   Islam? Recently I’ve had these thoughts and I’m worried it will weaken
>   my faith in Islam. Is this a common problem amongst Muslims?

Don't ever allow anybody to tell you not to question something. It's not really you who is questioning. It is Allah acting through you. Question everything always! And please don't believe anything I have written. Maybe just take them as interesting information and something to contemplate about.